# Authenticating with dropbox api oauth 2.0 with nodejs and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ejs, dropbox-api

**Nodejs in controller:**

I have used a function **file_upload** using a parameter **content** in which the file will be pass. In this code when I tried to console.log the req.files it shows me **null**. So my problem, is my file passing through the content parameter or not? If not then what is the way to pass a file?

```
module.exports.fileUpload = function(req, res){
    if(!req.files){
        console.log('File not uploaded!');
    } else {
        upload_file(req.file);
    }
};

var token = << token here >>;

function upload_file(content){
    console.log(content);
    var options = {
        url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Dropbox-API-Arg': {'path': '/' + content, 'mute': false, 'mode': 'add', 'autorename': true}
        },
        body: content
    }
    return options;
};
```

I'm using jquery post method to upload the file and to send the request to the controller.

**Html**

```html
    <form class="form-control" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" class="input-form" name="file" id="file">
        <button type="submit" class="upload-btn" id="upload-btn">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#upload-btn').click(function(){
        var inputFile = $('#file')[0].files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', inputFile, inputFile.name);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/dropbox',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(response){
            alert(response);
        }).fail(function(response){
            alert(response.responseText);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I used formData to get the file but it still not working.

That's what I have done so far. Can you guys please tell me my problem and why it's not working?

Comment: I think you should edit the question title to something more clear, like *"Problem authenticating with dropbox api"* for instance

Answer (score 0):

I did dropbox file upload but i am using file path, may be you will get something..

```
  var _uploadFile = function (req,res) {

        __fileData = fs.createReadStream(Your file path);
        var url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';
        var path = '{\"path\": \"' + folder + '/' + filename + '\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}';
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.body.auth.access_token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'Dropbox-API-Arg': path
            },
            body: __fileData
        };
        request(options, function (err, response) {
            if (err) {
                res.send({data: 'error'});
            } else if (JSON.parse(response.body).error_summary) {
                res.send({data: 'Please provide valid file path'});
            } else {
                res.send('success');
            }
        });
    }
```